# How can I keep the anchors and aliases as the are?

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

E.g. input file

```
username: &username john
password: &password  xyz
server: &servername 192.168.0.1
host:
 server: *servername
 username: *username
 password: *password
```

output file is showing `null` instead of the `*servername` `*username` `*password`, if O do `yaml.dump`

```
username: &username john
password: &password  xyz
server: &servername 192.168.0.1
host:
 server: null
 username: null
 password: null
```

reading like this

```
with open(file_name, 'r') as file: 
    loaded_data = yaml.safe_load(file)
```

writing

```
with open('filename.yaml', 'w') as f: 
    data = yaml.dump(loaded_data, f, sort_keys=False,default_flow_style=False,allow_unicode = True, indent=2)
```

Comment: yes, it is defined
server: &servername  xyz
user: &username john

Comment: How are you reading the input file?

Comment: Your code does not emit `null` for me. Are you sure that this is not caused by some code you *don't* show?

Answer (score 2):

For round-trip (loading, changing, dumping) of YAML in Python I recommend using `ruamel.yaml`
(disclaimer: I am the author of that package). It supports YAML 1.2, preserves comments and tags (even
when tagging simple scalars as in your case), none of which PyYAML can do:

```py
import sys
from pathlib import Path
import ruamel.yaml

in_file = Path('input.yaml')
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.indent(mapping=1)       # to match your input, default is 2
data = yaml.load(in_file)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)  # replace sys.stdout with in_file to overwrite the input
```

which gives:

```
username: &username john
password: &password xyz
server: &servername 192.168.0.1
host:
 server: *servername
 username: *username
 password: *password
```

Comment: Hi Anthon,
Thanks for help!!
The above issue got resolved.
However after dumping it is removing ( double quotes  ") from file and also sometimes " is being replaced by ' ( single quotes)

Comment: Have you tried setting `yaml.preserve_quotes = True` ? By default `ruamel.yaml` normalizes quotes: removing those unnecessary, using the more restrictive single quotes when quoting is necessary.

Comment: Just tried and its working fine.
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using StackOverflow to find an answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/69558506/1307905